# How to return two dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, django

How do I return two dicts in Python?

Below is my `views.py`

```
def index(request):
    dests = photo.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index.html", {'dests':dests})


def gallery(request):
   gals = wedding.objects.all()
   return render(request, "gallery.html", 'gals':gals)
```

Comment: you want to return both queryset seperately via one view or you want to combine both querysets and send it from one view  ?

Comment: Please make sure to include in questions: What are you trying to do and what is happening instead(including error messages etc.)

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: Return them in a tuple e.g: `return object_1, object_2` then you can access them by index e.g `obj = index(request)` to access first dictionary `obj[0]` then to access second `obj[1]`.

Comment: yes I want return both on two different pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
#views.py 

# your imports 

dests = photo.objects.all()
gals = wedding.objects.all()
context = {'dests':dests,
           'gals' :gals 
           }
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html",context)
def gallery(request):
   return render(request, "gallery.html",context)
```

in template you can access both dict as **`dests, gals`**

Comment: Hey, thank you for given the code but I have a problem. but some time its work but not the all times.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you can define a new function and use the both functions defined before.

```
def newFunction(request):
 return index(request),gallery(request)
```